# How to Handle Insertion Error in Room Android

Tags: android, android-room

i'm looking for solution on how can we handle room exception while inserting a user entry.
I have an Entity Class with Unique constraint for email & conflict strategy for same is ABORT.

Now i'm getting an exception in repository class in Coroutine Scope. Now i want to display the error message to user and let him know to email address already exists. How can i achieve that?

**Function in ViewModel which calls UserRepository Method**

```
fun setupUser() {
    
    val serviceDate =
        DateUtils.stringToMillis(serviceInDate.value ?: DateUtils.getFutureDateInString(4))
    val oilDate =
        DateUtils.stringToMillis(oilInDate.value ?: DateUtils.getFutureDateInString(4))
    val lubeDate =
        DateUtils.stringToMillis(lubeInDate.value ?: DateUtils.getFutureDateInString(1))
    val user = User(
        name = name,
        email = email,
        photoUrl = null,
        lubingIntervalInKms = (lubeInKms.value ?: "300").toInt(),
        lubingIntervalInDate = lubeDate,
        serviceIntervalInKms = (serviceInKms.value ?: "4000").toInt(),
        serviceIntervalInDate = serviceDate,
        oilingIntervalInKms = (oilInKms.value ?: "5000").toInt(),
        oilingIntervalInDate = oilDate,
    )
    userRepository.insertUser(user)
}
```

**UserRepository.kt**

```
class UserRepository(private val appDatabase: AppDatabase) {

val tag = "UserRepository"

fun insertUser(user: User){
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        try {
           appDatabase.userDao().insertUser(user)
        } catch (e: SQLiteException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

**UserDao.kt**

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = ABORT, entity = User::class)
    fun insertUser(user: User)
}
```

Is there any way to know the reason of insert query failure inside `viewmodel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `viewModel` to handle the exceptions you need to let it. (btw: it throws specific exception that tells you what happened - [SQLiteAbortException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteAbortException))

Make `insertUser` suspendable and launch it within the `viewModelScope`(which is something you should be doing anyway).

You can either create a wrapper around SQLite exceptions(some `Result` class for the operation) so you can consolidate some of them. But you can also just use them "raw".

Room already supports coroutines so there isn't much you need to change.

DAO:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = ABORT, entity = User::class)
    suspend fun insertUser(user: User)
}
```

Repository:

```
class UserRepository(private val appDatabase: AppDatabase) {

    suspend fun insertUser(user: User) {
        appDatabase.insertUser(user)
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
fun setupUser() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
           userRepository.insertUser(user)
        } catch (e: SQLiteAbortException) {
           e.printStackTrace()
    }

}
```

Comment: Can we get user friendly exception message instead of "UNIQUE constraint failed: User.email (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE[2067])" or i have to manually construct this?

Comment: @Sam I think at that point you would have to parse the exception message and show message you want.